# How to manually add labels to plot or map the dictionary efficiently to display on your plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, matplotlib

I am working with two `Pandas dataframes`. In the first `dataframe`. I am interested in matching the `ProductID` with the `CompanyName` that purchased a product.

In order to solve this problem matching. I first create an `empty dictionary` and then `loop` through the `rows` of the `dataframe` and `update` the `dictionary` as shown below

```py
Slice = {}
for i,j in df.iterrows():
    Slice.update({j.ProductID:j.CompanyName})
```

Now I am trying to plot the `productID` and put a `label` of the company the `ProductID` is associated with

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(30,25))
color = ["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#008080", "#FF00FF",
          "#FFD088", "#B3AFB2", "#A9CCE3", "#3333eb"]
figure1 = df.ProductID.value_counts().nlargest(8).plot(kind="bar", color=color)
figure1.tick_params(labelsize=30)
Tar_1 = [Slice[124],Slice[920],Slice[162],Slice[166], Slice[165], Slice[923],Slice[1759], Slice[476]]

plt.legend(handles=Tar_1)
```

I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_label'`

Please how can I resolve this issue? Or do you have a better approach? I was thinking of `mapping` the `productID` from the dictionary created but the column created generated all `NaN`

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the best way to solve this problem was to indeed convert the two columns of interest to a dictionary and then map that dictionary to the column.

```
map_obj = dict(df[['ProductID', 'CompanyName']].values)
df['Product_Company'] = df['ProductID'].map(map_obj)
```